# How do I unlock a Simulink library to make it editable?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simulink-library

Simple question - how do I unlock a Simulink (i.e. part of MATLAB) block library to edit it?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to unlock a library:

1. Direct UI method - Ultra-simple, good in at least Matlab 2019a and later - after opening the library, in the bottom left corner of the library window, there is a "lock" icon. Click it.

   [image]

   The Library will automatically relock after saving and closing it.
2. Programmatically Unlock the Library

   - Open the library (directly or programmatically)
   - Use the following code, where `my_library` is the base name of the library without the `*.slx` extension:

```matlab
set_param('my_library', 'Lock', 'off');
```

***Note:***

- *If the library is currently the Simulink window in focus, you can use the `gcs` command (get current system) instead of the `my_library` name.*
- ```matlab
  set_param(gcs, 'Lock', 'off');
  ```